# Add new value to variable on every new function run without losing the old ones (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add a variable to the existing ones at every new function run, without losing the old ones?

Function example:

```
// this div value gets changes by an other click event
<div class="data">204</div>

$(".button").on('click', function(){
  var data = $('.data').text();
  var dataCollection = data + data; // + new data, the old ones should not be deleted
  console.log(dataCollection); // here I wanna see a list of all data
});
```

Comment: hard to tell what your problem is. What is the exact code that has the issue?

Comment: @epascarello I have added some more details on my question, maybe it helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not redefine the variable each time. What you are doing would make more sense as an array.

```
var dataCollection = [];
$(".button").on('click', function(){
  var data = $('.data').text();
  dataCollection.push(data)
  console.log(dataCollection);
});
```

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand! Big thx - that makes sense!

Comment: @Pepe - Note the other critical thing that espascarello did here that you were missing in your examples was defining `dataCollection` _outside_ of the callback function being used as a click handler, so that it would remain in memory after the callback completed execution and exited.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Yes, thats right - also thx for the info.